# How to apply Qt Graphical Effect on Delegate of Repeater in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to apply the QtGraphicalEffect `ColorOverlay` to an `Image` in a `Repeater` delegate. The problem is that I have to set the `id` of the `Image` as the `source` of the `ColorOverlay`, but I don't know the `id`, because it is dynamically created by the `Repeater`.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    id:mainItem
    width: 800
    height: 400

    property string vorneColor: "red"

    ListModel {
        id: safeRailModel
        ListElement {name: "vorne"; imageSource:"images/saferail/ring_vorne.png";}
        ListElement {name: "vorneLinks"; imageSource:"images/saferail/ring_vorne_links.png"; }
    }

    Component {
        id: imageDelegate
        Image {
            source: imageSource
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            opacity: 1
            visible: true
        }
    }

    Repeater {
        id: safeRailRepeater
        model: safeRailModel
        delegate: imageDelegate
    }

    Component {
        id: effectsDelegate
        Item{
            id:effectsItem
            ColorOverlay {
                anchors.fill: safeRailRepeater.itemAt(index)// <-- This doesn't work
                source: safeRailRepeater.itemAt(index)// <-- This doesn't work
                color: vorneColor
            }
        }
    }

    Repeater {
        id: safeRailEffectsRepeater
        model: safeRailModel
        delegate: effectsDelegate
    }
}
```

How can I set `source` and `anchors.fill` properties?

I searched everywhere, but I've only found something along the lines of `safeRailRepeater.itemAt(index)` or `safeRailRepeater.itemAt(index).item` but neither the former nor the latter works.

Side note: the `ColorOverlay` doesn't need to be in a seperate delegate and `Repeater`.

It would be great if somebody has a solution for this problem or could point me in the right direction.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `itemAt()` function call returns `null` because the other `Repeater` hasn't loaded its items yet. Also, the function call won't ever be reevaluated, because none of its arguments ever change, so you'll always get `null`.

The design is a bit odd though; I'd suggest moving the `ColorOverlay` into the same delegate, as you mentioned that it doesn't have to be in a separate `Repeater`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    id: mainItem
    width: 800
    height: 400
    visible: true

    property string vorneColor: "red"

    ListModel {
        id: safeRailModel
        ListElement { name: "vorne"; vorneColor: "salmon"; }
        ListElement { name: "vorneLinks"; vorneColor: "steelblue"; }
    }
    Component {
        id: imageDelegateComponent
        Rectangle {
            id: delegate
            color: "grey"
            opacity: 1
            visible: true
            width: 64
            height: 64

            layer.enabled: true
            layer.effect: ColorOverlay {
                color: vorneColor
            }
        }
    }
    Row {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        Repeater {
            id: safeRailRepeater
            model: safeRailModel
            delegate: imageDelegateComponent
        }
    }
}
```

Using the [`layer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#item-layers) API of `Item` is a convenient way of specifying graphical effects.

I also changed the `Image` to a `Rectangle`, since we don't have access to those images, and put the `Repeater` within a row, so that you can see all of the delegates.

Comment: Great! This works perfect. Thank you very much @Mitch!